# Xamarin.iOS app - slower on iOS10 than iOS9

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Our app has some performance issues. One particular area is the opening of a `UITabBarController`.

I have tested the app with `Debug` and `Ad-Hoc` builds built with VS 2015. I am using

- Xamarin 4.5
- Xamarin.iOS 10.10.0

I am testing on real devices

1. iPhone 6 iOS 10.1.1
2. iPhone 6 iOS 9.2
3. Pad Air 2 iOS 9.3.1
4. iPhone 5 iOS 10

I am seeing consistent and significant performance gains from the iOS 9 devices.

With the `Ad-Hoc` build, opening of the view, with a large dataset, takes just under 6 seconds (5.8). Opening the same View with the same data and same build takes just over 1 second on the iOS9 devices.

**Can anyone suggest why iOS9 would be performing so much better?**

We do not have anything that runs on iOS 10 only. The closest we have to that are calls like this:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(9, 0))
```

However that check would return true for 9 and 10.

Comment: We can only speculate here. How did you measure those times? Have checked the app with Instruments? Are there other circumstances that might be a cause?

Comment: I have a series of steps that I have ran through 6 times for each step. I then take the average of those times. We don't have Xamarin Profiler as it requires a Enterprise license that we don't have (yet)

Comment: ...using a digital stopwatch (previous comment was no longer editable)

Comment: It's still hard to tell. Speaking of profiling, I didn't meant Xamarin Profiler. Xcode comes with it's one called Instruments. I prefer this one because it monitors the native side of my app. And this is the one I am normally more interested in.